# Unable to use AWS DynamoDB in my android studio application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get values from 3 text fields and put them into a table in dynamodb. However, I am facing some issues. Any help would be appreciated .

```
package com.example.smart_pill;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the input fields and submit button
        EditText nameEditText = findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText dosageEditText = findViewById(R.id.dosage);
        EditText timeEditText = findViewById(R.id.time);
        Button submitButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // Set up the click listener for the submit button
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Get the values from the input fields
                String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
                String dosage = dosageEditText.getText().toString();
                String time = timeEditText.getText().toString();
                DynamoDBManager.putThreeVariables(name, dosage, time);

            }
        });
    }
}

Error
```

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.smart_pill, PID: 23443
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/management/MBeanServerFactory;
at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.getMBeanServer(MBeans.java:111)
at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.registerMBean(MBeans.java:50)
at com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.registerMetricAdminMBean(SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.java:27)
at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.registerMetricAdminMBean(AwsSdkMetrics.java:398)
at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.(AwsSdkMetrics.java:359)
at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.addAll(AwsSdkMetrics.java:662)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:79)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.build(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.java:109)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.build(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.java:30)
at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
at com.example.smart_pill.DynamoDBManager.putThreeVariables(DynamoDBManager.java:24)
at com.example.smart_pill.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.management.MBeanServerFactory" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.smart_pill/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~yJ2sTpKtnIbLISoFh7fuBg==/com.example.smart_pill-kShJyhRIP04OebNat7K7og==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~yJ2sTpKtnIbLISoFh7fuBg==/com.example.smart_pill-kShJyhRIP04OebNat7K7og==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)

```
Dynamodbclass
```

public class DynamoDBManager {

```
private static final String ACCESS_KEY = "";
private static final String SECRET_KEY = "/";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "";
private static final Regions REGION = Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1;

public static void putThreeVariables(String variable1, String variable2, 
String variable3) {
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new 
BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new 
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials);
    AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder builder = 
AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new 
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .withRegion(REGION);
    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(builder.build());
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(TABLE_NAME);
    Item item = new Item()
            .withPrimaryKey("Variable1", variable1)
            .withString("Variable2", variable2)
            .withString("Variable3", variable3);
    table.putItem(item);
}
```

}

Comment: My guess is that you are using the AWS Java SDK which may use features/APIs unavailable to Android. Do look at AWS Amplify, https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android